# I get fields of type String with some Unicode characters instead of the usual

Tags: android, retrofit2

My problem is that I am getting strings where some characters are Unicode.

```
"fieldName": "Ac6jHguQjKKUxx6MSOpjO2kOLKPAdjStVs1pgTGNSU8\u003d"
```

Then I immediately send such a string to another API and the server returns me an error with a code of 500. If I use this string in postman and replace the unicode with a normal one, then the code 200 is returned from the server.
I thought there was a problem in the server, but they checked it and said that they were sending it as expected.
How do I translate Unicode?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [URLDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder). Here is an example.

```java
String str = "Ac6jHguQjKKUxx6MSOpjO2kOLKPAdjStVs1pgTGNSU8\u003d";
String decode = URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(decode);
//Ac6jHguQjKKUxx6MSOpjO2kOLKPAdjStVs1pgTGNSU8=
```